# Changing text after a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible in jquery to insert text after a **span**. For example, I would like to change the price value after the dollar sign below.

```
<div id="price">
    <span>$</span>
    10.00
</div>
```

The only way I can see how to do this, is to remove the span element (store as variable), add the price value, and then append the currency value again. Seems pretty hacky.

Comment: You can do it by accessing (and modifying the value of) the textnode holding the amount, like shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/7mdygLLs/

Comment: why is this down voted, and voted to close?

Comment: I wonder why too. Can't find anything wrong with the question at all.

Comment: @Oliver Watkins: that DOM looks kinda quirky

Comment: Whoever down voted this question please specify reason so that questioner can correct his mistake from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the price using `lastChild` and `nodeValue` like following.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price">
    <span>$</span>
    10.00
</div>

<script>
    var price = $('#price')[0];
    price.lastChild.nodeValue = "155.00";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it as:

```
$("#price").contents(":not(span)").text("Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another span to wrap around the price value.

```
<div id="price">
    <span>$</span>
    <span id="price-value">10.00</span>
</div>
```

Then you can `$("#price-value")` to manipulate that part on its own.

Answer (score 1):

One another way

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price">
    <span>$</span>
    10.00
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#price').contents().last()[0].textContent=' 20.00';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a much easier alternative, one might also use CSS to prepend the currency symbol. This avoids using the span altogether and allows changing the currency symbol.

**CSS Examples:**

```
.currency div::before {  content: "$" }
.currency.yen div::before { content: "¥" }
```

**And a working code snippet:**

```js
$('#item1').html('10.00');

$('#item2').html('8.80'); 
                       
$('#item3').html( '20.30');
```

```css
.currency.dollar div::before {  content: "$" }
.currency.pound div::before {  content: "£" }

.currency {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px lightgray solid;
  width: 8em;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="currency dollar">

  <div id="item1"></div>

  <div id="item2"></div>

  <div id="item3"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$("#pri").text("100");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price">
    <span id='si'>$</span>
    <span id='pri'>10.00</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text need some old fashioned JavaScript assistance. Using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```js
$('#price').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).last()[0].textContent = 'changed';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price">
  <span>$</span>
  10.00
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try insertAfter() in jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<button>Insert span element after span element</button>
<br>
<div id="price">
<span>$</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     $("<span>100</span>").insertAfter("span");
  });
});
```